# Cant insert into a table using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

i have this code and when i try to access laravel.dev/cats/create a page appears:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

this is my route.php code(important parts):

```
Route::model('cat', 'Cat');

Route::get('cats/create', function() {
    $cat = new Cat;
    return View::make('cats.edit')
        ->with('cat', $cat)
        ->with('method', 'post');
});

Route::post('cats', function(){
    $cat = Cat::create(Input::all());
    return Redirect::to('cats/' . $cat->id)
        ->with('message', 'Successfully created page!');
});
Route::get('cats/{id}', function($id) {
    $cat = Cat::find($id);
    return View::make('cats.single')
        ->with('cat', $cat);
});
```

and this is my cats/edit.blade.php code:

```
@extends('master')
@section('header')
<a href="{{('cats/'.$cat->id.'')}}">&larr; Cancel </a>
    <h2>
    @if($method == 'post')
        Add a new cat
    @elseif($method == 'delete')
        Delete {{$cat->name}}?
    @else
        Edit {{$cat->name}}
    @endif
</h2>
@stop

@section('content')
    {{Form::model($cat, array('method' => $method, 'url'=>
    'cats/'.$cat->id))}}

@unless($method == 'delete')
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('Name')}}
        {{Form::text('name')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('Date of birth')}}
        {{Form::text('date_of_birth')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('Breed')}}
        {{Form::select('breed_id', $breed_options)}}
    </div>
    {{Form::submit("Save", array("class"=>"btn btn-default"))}}
@else
    {{Form::submit("Delete", array("class"=>"btn btn-default"))}}
@endif
    {{Form::close()}}
@stop
```

i dont now where the problem , i have the same code for edit and delete but those guys work correctly but this one no!

this is the error that debugger reports:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\cats\single.blade.php)

<?php echo e($cat->name); ?>
```

error mention that line.

Thanks for Your helps:))))

**Edit:**
and this is single.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')
@section('header')
<?php// dd($cat); ?>
<a href="{{url('/')}}">Back to overview</a>
<h2>
    {{{$cat->name}}}
</h2>
<a href="{{url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/edit')}}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
</a>
<a href="{{url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/delete')}}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
</a>
Last edited: {{$cat->updated_at}}
@stop
@section('content')
    <p>Date of Birth: {{$cat->date_of_birth}} </p>
    <p>
        @if($cat->breed)
            Breed:
            {{link_to('cats/breeds/' . $cat->breed->name,
            $cat->breed->name)}}
        @endif
    </p>
@stop
```

i don't know why when i was go to cats/create i passes to single.blade.php i think this is where i'm going wrong but no idea where in code i do that

Comment: Turn on debugging in `app/config/app.php` and you'll get a useful error message

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: Look at your data , try dd($cat) at the beginning of the view. see what is null.

Comment: The problem is that you show completely different file. The message is about `single.blade.php` and not `edit.blade.php` file. You probably include somewhere this `single.blade.php` file. You should add its content to the question

Comment: @MattBurrow , i get only NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
Route::get('cats/{id}', function($id) {
    $cat = Cat::find($id);
    return View::make('cats.single')
        ->with('cat', $cat);
});
```

It seems that there is no record found with `$id`, so `$cat` is `null` here and it won't work in Blade.

You should check what's the current url (what's the $id value) and make sure that there is a record with such $id in table).

Comment: so why the debugger get error from single.blade.php?

Comment: @Nabialek       when i use `dd($cat)` in first of single.blade.php its returns NULL only , what part of code do u want to i show u?

Comment: @ArmanKuroKy You still haven't showed this piece of code where you use `View::make('cats.single.blade.php')...`

Comment: i found the error , i think `cats\{id}` and `cats\create` have conflict and create known as an id and i got error i move `cats\create` upper than `cats\{id}` and every thing going ok